# Function won’t read value of global variable - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global-variables, settimeout

I'm having trouble here. I have one variable that is supposed to have two states. I want to check to see if the state has changed, and even though it has, my function continues to say that it hasn't. Take a look:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
//More unrelated code here
function Talk(url) {
 just_done = 0;
 //alert("Hey!");
 buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
 //alert("Hey!");
 if (url == "scheduler.html" && talk == 0 && just_done == 0) {
  trc = parseInt(getCookie("trc"));
  if (getCookie("trc") == "NaN") {
   trc = 0;
  }
  if ((getCookie("trc")) == undefined) {
   trc = 0;
  }
  //alert("It started.");
  stop = 0;
  buttons[0].value="          Stop Listening          ";
  iframe[0].src=url;
  //alert("It should be removed");
  talk = 1;
  just_done = 1;
 }
 if (url == "scheduler.html" && talk == 1 && just_done == 0) {
  //alert("It stopped.");
  stop = 1;
  full_time = getTimeSince() + klove;
  document.cookie="klove=" + full_time;
  buttons[0].value="          Listen Now          ";
  iframe[0].src="";
  // //alert("It should be removed");
  talk = 0;
  just_done = 1;
  //alert(full_time);
 }
 if (url == "http://emf.mp3.miisolutions.net:80/kl/klove_itunes" && music == 0 && just_done == 0) {
  klove = parseInt(getCookie("klove"));
  if ((getCookie("klove")) == "NaN") {
   klove = 0;
   //alert("K-Love seemed to be null.");
  }
  if ((getCookie("klove")) == undefined) {
   klove = 0;
  }
  //alert("It started.");
  stop = 0;
  iframe[0].src=url;
  // //alert("It should be removed");
  music = 1;
  just_done = 1;
 }
 if (url == "http://emf.mp3.miisolutions.net:80/kl/klove_itunes" && music == 1 && just_done == 0) {
  //alert("It stopped.");
  stop = 1;
  full_time = getTimeSince() + klove;
  document.cookie="klove=" + full_time;
  iframe[0].src="";
  // //alert("It should be removed");
  music = 0;
  just_done = 1;
  //alert(full_time);
 }
 if (url == "http://tunein.streamguys1.com/cnn" && news == 0 && just_done == 0) {
  cnn = parseInt(getCookie("cnn"));
  if ((getCookie("cnn")) == "NaN") {
   cnn = 0;
   //alert("CNN seemed to be null.");
  }
  if ((getCookie("cnn")) == undefined) {
   cnn = 0;
  }
  //alert("It started.");
  stop = 0;
  iframe[0].src=url;
  // //alert("It should be removed");
  news = 1;
  just_done = 1;
 }
 if (url == "http://tunein.streamguys1.com/cnn" && news == 1 && just_done == 0) {
  //alert("It stopped.");
  stop = 1;
  full_time = getTimeSince() + cnn;
  document.cookie="cnn=" + full_time;
  iframe[0].src="";
  // //alert("It should be removed");
  news = 0;
  just_done = 1;
  //alert(full_time);
 }
}
stop = 0;
Time();
function Time() {
 if (stop == 0) {
 i = i + 1;
 alert(i);
 setTimeout(Time, 1000);
 }
 if (stop != 0) {
 alert("I'm done. It's " + i);
 }
}
</script>
<input width="10px" height="6px" id="button" type="button" onClick='Talk("scheduler.html")' value="          Listen Now          "></input>
```

Strange that I have this issue, I’ve followed EVERYBODY’s instructions on this very site when they have similar issues, and yet this still won’t work.

EDIT: Let me add that the if statement that sets stop to 1 is within another function.

EDIT 2: Here is more code, so you can trigger my issue.

Comment: I don't see where you change `stop` **after** you run the `Time()` function.

Comment: The function changing stop is run later. You must hit a button to activate it.

Comment: You only setTimeout for 1 second. Are you sure you hit the button quick enough?

Comment: Where is *i* defined? You need to provide something that actually replicates your problem and does not contain spurious errors.

Comment: @ColorCodin it's not obvious from your code. It's impossible to help with code we don't see. For the provided example of code it will not work that way because you don't change `stop` after timer is started.

Comment: My guess is that you want `else if` instead of `if`, so that you don't change the state back immediately.

Comment: Thanks! I didn’t think of that.